# Are 4-float colors faster than 4-byte colors?

Tags: performance, caching, graphics

Let's say that I'm defining a vertex structure. I can keep the vertex structure small by packing the vertex's RGBA color into a single unsigned int. Thus:

```
struct Vertex
{
    float pos[3];
    float normal[3];
    float texcoord[2];
    unsigned int color;    // RGBA
};
```

Yet when the vertex arrives at my vertex shader, it will have been converted to a 4-float value: a vec4 in GLSL or a float4 in HLSL. Presumably this type conversion takes some time on the GPU.

Would it therefore be faster to define the vertex's color attribute as a 4-float, thus avoiding the conversion?

```
...
float color[4];
...
```

Or would the larger memory size of this color make the GPU cache less efficient and result in *slower* rendering?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modern GPUs have dedicated hardware for unpacking packed formats on load so the conversion is effectively free. The reduced memory bandwidth requirements and more efficient vertex cache usage will improve performance so as a rule you should pack all vertex attributes as tightly as possible while still maintaining sufficient precision for your purposes.